# Why MockMvc could not test @WebServlet in spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/test")
public class TestWebServlet  extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setStatus(200);
        resp.getWriter().println("test");
    }
}
```

main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ServletComponentScan
public class Demo20Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo20Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

test code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class Demo20ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testMockMvc() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/test"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}



java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :404
```

the servlet send a 200 status code but test result shows me the status is 404

It seems that the MockMvc can not be used to test servlets in spring boot

Answer (score 4):

`MockMvc` is used to test *controllers* (i.e. components that you define a `@Controller` that has some method with `@RequestMapping` on them). MockMvc allows you to test your web layer without starting a servlet container and mock the servlet context for you.

You are creating a raw servlet completely outside of this environment. So, no, this is not supported.